# Python Selenium, Error with find_element_by() command

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I don't know the reason for this error, for some reason the find_element_by_() commands are not being recognized, I've already tried to reinstall everything, I changed the Python version, nothing works, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: Error: Unresolved attribute reference 'find_element_by_name' for class 'WebDriver]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_*` methods are now deprecated.
`find_element(By.` are used now.
So, instead of `find_element_by_name` it is a `driver.find_element(By.NAME, "name_attribute")` now.
Similarly `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath_locator")` etc.
To use these methods you will need the following import:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but why does the same code using find_element_by on another my other pc work normal? Could it be because of the Python version? In this one that gave a problem I'm using 3.7, on the other pc that works I use Python 3.9

Comment: Probably you installed Selenium 4 on this PC.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import **By** from selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

then you would format your code like this

```
dv.find_elements(By.NAME,"<enter name value>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer for python but in c# this how you do it

```
browser.FindElement(By.Name("NameofElement"));
```

Found this example for python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Here
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html